# oauth & POSTing JSON

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, oauth

Reading [section 9.1](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process) of OAuth Core 1.0, I only see a reference to performing `POST` requests using `content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

- How does one go about performing POST requests with JSON data in the request body?
- How does handle the signing?  Is it at all possible?
- Can this work on AppEngine?

Comment: Did you find anything out about this? I was just wondering the exact same thing.

Comment: no status update on this on my end.

Comment: I did just a bit of preliminary investigating, and it looks like if you're posting raw JSON, the signature base string won't include the post body. This means that the client and server signatures will match, but the POST body won't actually be signed. Seems off to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have urlencoded the JSON, then unencoded on the other end in the past. I don't really know anything about AppEngine though, sorry.